# Reminder/Alarm in ionic 2

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, reminders

I am trying to implement reminder/alarm after a certain period of time in ionic2.I have found this plugin https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer but I want to implement it using typescript as this is no recognizing window.wakeuptimer using in the below-mentioned code:

```
window.wakeuptimer.wakeup( successCallback,  
   errorCallback, 

   // a list of alarms to set

   {

        alarms : [{

            type : 'onetime',

            time : { hour : 14, minute : 30 },

            extra : { message : 'json containing app-specific information to be posted when alarm triggers' }, 

            message : 'Alarm has expired!'

       }] 

   }

);
```

Can anyone help me out in this

Answer (score 7):

The plugin you are attempting to use is almost 3 years old. Older than Ionic 2 itself. You should look at the native plugins listed at https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/

In the past I have used the **Local Notifications** plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/local-notifications/) to handle reminders/alarms.

It is quite simple to schedule, all you have to do is create a Date object for the time you wish to notify. Here is an example using the data you provided:

```
import { LocalNotifications } from 'ionic-native';


// Schedule delayed notification 

LocalNotifications.schedule({
   text: 'Alarm has expired!',
   at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600),
   sound: isAndroid ? 'file://sound.mp3': 'file://beep.caf',
   data: { message : 'json containing app-specific information to be posted when alarm triggers' }
});
```

Comment: what if I want to trigger every day at the same time?

Comment: Did you figure it out? @Esco

Comment: @Esco do you have any idea for trigger every day?

Comment: Guys, just read the manual :D https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#properties-2

Answer (score 1):

To trigger it repeatedly, you can use below code. It will trigger notification daily. [Reference](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#repeating)

```
import { LocalNotifications, ILocalNotification } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';

const timeAt = new Date(this.notifyAt);
const hour = timeAt.getHours();
const minute = timeAt.getMinutes();

const title = 'Notify...';
const text = 'Hi, this is test notification.';

const notifications: ILocalNotification[] = Array(7).fill(0).map((_, idx) => {
    return { title, text, trigger: { every: {weekday: idx + 1, hour, minute} }
};
});

this.localNotifications.schedule(notifications);
```